# Google App Engine Deployment Error 409

Tags: java, google-app-engine, deployment

I am getting `error 409 Conflict` with following message

> Deployment of this version has not yet started

I tried to deploy to new version, update existing version and also tried rollback but during deployment everything goes fine until the last step and it finally displays

> Uploading 0 Files
>
> Deployment of this version has not yet started

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug in the 1.7.0 admin console. We're working on a fix. This issue has been fixed now. 10/11/2012

Comment: If you're still experiencing problems it is a different issue. Please use the tracker to report it, don't just downvote me.

Comment: This issue is being fixed now. Works fine on console . specify the backend name to roll back after the package name

Answer (score 0):

I think they're in the middle of preparing the production environment for 1.7.0 (and probably staging some I/O-related shenanigans for the morning).  I had 1.6.5 python SDK for Windows and it blocked me (same as you).  1.7.0, same error.  Grab 1.6.6 and it seems to work fine:

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/downloads/detail?name=GoogleAppEngine-1.6.6.msi&can=1&q=python+1.6.6